# MouseUp doesn't fire if MouseDown is present in the same Chart private code

Tags: excel, vba

I have a chart on a sheet. I want a label to be shown while the left button is down, and then disappear when the left button goes back up.

But if both event handlers are present, then the MouseDown fires, but the MouseUp doesn't. If I quote-comment the MouseDown handler, the MouseUp starts firing.

Other weird things happen also, like Excel crashing after two or three clicks on the chart. It is getting me crazy. Here are both event handlers. I've minimized the code.

```
Private Sub Chart_MouseDown(ByVal Button As Long, _
       ByVal Shift As Long, ByVal X As Long, ByVal Y As Long)
           Me.Labels.Add(X - 100, Y - 100, 60, 30).Characters.Text = "This is a test"
End Sub

Private Sub Chart_MouseUp(ByVal Button As Long, _
       ByVal Shift As Long, ByVal X As Long, ByVal Y As Long)
    Dim i
       For Each i In Me.Shapes
          i.Delete
       Next i
End Sub
```